# Applying low-pass filter to a signal

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

I have the following signal:

$$ f(t) = 60\operatorname{sinc}(24t) + (30\operatorname{sinc}(10t) \cdot \cos(40\pi t) )
$$

and I should apply an ideal low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of $ 10\mathrm{Hz} $.
Now, by applying the fourier transform to the functions above I get (please guide me if I'm wrong):
$$
\frac{5}{2}\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{24}\right) + 3\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{10}\right) \ast \frac{1}{2}[\delta(f - 40) + \delta(f+40)]
$$

At this point what should i do? Multiply by a rect built from the $ 10\mathrm{Hz} $ cutoff frequency?

Thanks,

Comment: in the second expression you shall replace $t$ with $f$, then ,yes, you shall multiply by a $rect$ with 10Hz cutoff